# How to change the section font to specific size by using \titleformat?

Tags: sectioning, fontsize, titlesec

I want to set the section font to the specific size and type. But using \titleformat can only give few standard types, like Large, large...

```
\titleformat*{\section}{\LARGE\headingfont} 
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\Large\headingfont} 
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\large\headingfont}
```

I wonder is there any way to use

```
\fontencoding{OT1}\fontfamily{cmr}\fontseries{m}\fontshape{n}\fontsize{11pt}{11}\selectfont
```

to change the section font size? 
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply use your commands as arguments for `\titleformat*`:

```
\titleformat*{\section}{\fontencoding{OT1}\fontfamily{cmr}\fontseries{m}%
  \fontshape{n}\fontsize{11pt}{11}\selectfont}
```

Comment: It works. At the beginning i inserted one white space between \ and fontencoding accidently, so it always generate error. It took me a long time to figure it out. Thank you.